# Prevent checkbox from checking itself

Tags: javascript, dom-events, stoppropagation

I have some `<li>` which is styled as a button.

```
<li class="button">
   <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" />
   <span>Text</span>
</li>
```

As you can see, there is a checkbox inside the `li` element. I use angular to set `checked` property of this checkbox as we click `li` area. It works fine, but I have a problem. When I click the checkbox nothing happens - I know that my Angular code checks the checkbox and after this it unchecks itself.

I tried:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" onclick="event.stopPropagation()" />
```

But it didn't help... How to "block" checkbox from doing its "check/onlick" event?

Comment: have you tried `event.preventDefault();` ?

Comment: How about marking them as disabled or will that affect your designer's UI guidelines?

Comment: @AlexMcMillan Yes. The same effects :(

Comment: If the checkbox is functioning like a checkbox, why would you want to do it "yourself" in angular?

Comment: Sounds like you want a label, not a LI

Comment: No, no. The case is much more complicated, I need `li` here. I described it in the easiest way :)

Comment: Well, what you're describing is exactly what a label does, without any javascript, you'd just nest the label inside the LI, wrapping the rest of the content, and clicking it will check the checkbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return false` on checkbox to prevent its default behaviour

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" onclick="return false;" />
```